# PHP/Wordpress - Problems with negating conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, logical-operators

Sometimes when I try to post a php-snippet (with XYZ PHP CODE by XYZScripts) I get the following error:

Method Not Implemented
POST to /wp-admin/admin.php not supported.

I found out that it has to do with negating a conditions e. g. in a if-condition, like:

```
((!empty($_GET['test1'])) && (!empty($_GET['test2'])))      or
(!(empty($_GET['test1'])) && (empty($_GET['test2'])))

but (!empty($_GET['test1']) && !empty($_GET['test2'])) works
```

Another time I encountered this was the following:

```
!(error_reporting() & $severity)
```

Can somebody explain the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but too long to comment.  There's nothing negating about

```
((!empty($_GET['test1'])) && (!empty($_GET['test2'])))      or
(!(empty($_GET['test1'])) && (empty($_GET['test2'])))
```

Read it from left to right:

```
GET:test1 is not empty and GET:test2 is not empty 
OR
GET:test1 is not empty and GET:test2 is empty
```

Of course, this would be much better just written or spoken as:

```
GET:test1 is not empty
```

You'd do better to make your conditions simpler and more readable.

Ex. `!(empty($_GET['test1']))` should just be `!empty($_GET['test1'])`

Comment: Do you think, that wordpress or the add-on would not support such condition due to its complexity?